# Slovenia as the point of entry for schengen visa multiple entry and suggested trips

Tags: visas, schengen, indian-citizens, multiple-entry, slovenia

I want to get a multi entry Schengen visa . currently i am working in UK on a ICT 2 Tier Short term (My Nationality is Indian). I still have one month more to go to apply for the Schengen visa as the prerequisite documents for Visa filing are 3 months payslips. Kindly confirm if I should go for Slovenia as the point of entry for Schengen Visa (Based on stats of 2012 for multi entry). If yes please suggest the trips i should plan for 7 days from Slovenia. best and maximum countries i can cover in this span and also i would not end up in spending a lot.

Comment: Welcome! Please have a look at the [help] - asking for recommendations on routes is considered off topic, as each person has different preferences and it can't be answered objectively.  I recommend reading the rules in the help carefully, and then editing your question - in it's current state it's likely to be put on hold soon :/

Comment: Where have you been getting your stats from? Also, I see several problems with your plan. 7 days is very short, even for one country and travelling constantly will increase the cost so if you are on a budget you might just as well try to enjoy Slovenia. And if you want to apply for a visa from Slovenia, it needs to be the main destination so that there would be little time left and no point for a multiple-entry visa for such a short trip.

Comment: On the other hand, if your intent is really to go to other places in the Schengen area for a longer time, applying from Slovenia under the guise of a 7-day trip would simply be fraud.